# Is is okay for a SUP-pump to get wet?

Tags: gear, gear-care, water-sports

[Moved here from the sports exchange]

I have a Stand-Up-Paddle-Board, and I like to do some tours. I would need to take the pump with me. It's a typical pump for a SUP (double-action-pump with a pressure gage).

I wonder if it does matter, if the pump gets wet. Often water floats over the package area in the front when traveling on rivers, and I could even overturn and get the pump underwater. I was thinking about getting a huge Drybag to keep the pump dry. But I'm not sure if this is necessary? I guess most parts of the pump are made of plastic, and any water inside could possibly be emptied by pumping or turning the pump with no hose attached.

Would it be a problem, if it gets underwater?

Comment: But why not get the huge drybag anyway? They're not that expensive, and you'll need one for your other baggage anyway. The pump is likely not that big of an addition. If you don't wanna invest that much: Garbage bags tied tightly are okay enough for stuff that doesn't absolutely need to be dry

Comment: The pump is bigger than you may think, and the dimensions won't fit most drybags. But the idea with the garbage bag is actually pretty good, thanks!

Comment: Just beware that any small stick or sharp stone when landing/departing land can be enough to poke a hole/tear the bag. So it's not for stuff that needs to absolutely remain dry. But for this it should suffice :)

Answer (score 11):

I'm assuming you have some sort of barrel pump like this one pictured?

[image: Barrel Pump]

In short, it is fine but not great if it gets wet. The pump will work better and last longer if kept dry. Water will mess up the seal of the pump which makes it work less effectively. You also want to make sure you clear out the water by pumping with the hose not attached to your SUP before using it. Otherwise you can get water inside the SUP itself which can ruin the SUP over time.

The rafting company I used to work for kept our nice Carlson pumps dry but didn't care about the cheaper NRS/offbrand ones getting wet. So it is kind of up to you how much you want to care about keeping it dry.

For me personally for rafting, I keep barrel pumps dry, and have k-pump that I allow to get wet.

Comment: Additionally, if it gets wet then dry it on your return home, and give it a light overhaul at the end of the season before its packed away for winter.

Comment: @Criggie what exactly do you mean by overhaul?

Comment: Add-On for saltwater (if that is relevant): The salt in seawater can ruin your sealings very very quickly, so while the occasional lake-wetness may be ok, if youre paddling in saltwater carelessnes will have you buying a new pump fairly quickly

Comment: @Hobbamok Are you sure? These sealings are rubber-based, they shouldn't be much affected by salt water. Anything metalic would be much more of a problem.

Comment: @rcheetah overhaul would mean a disassembly, clean, re-grease, and if needed replacement O rings.  What you'd do before putting the pump away for 6 months of winter because leaving it with dirty canker water resting inside will have 6 months to cause damage.   If you're using the pump every week in summer then the buildup inside will be slower, and the warmth of summer will help limit liquids sitting inside.   Of course if you don't have winters (Bahamas ?), then this may not be reasonable.  You wouldn't store your board with salt crusted on it.

Comment: @Criggie thanks, I'll see if I can dismantle it without destroying it ^^ It was with the board, so I guess it's rather cheap.